# Azure Spell not detecting spelling mistakes

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, spell-checking

I've written up a quick proof of concept console app to test out the functionality of the AzureSpell Cognitive Services product, however it doesn't seem to often detect obvious spelling mistakes.

Having experimented with recommendations through other SO answers, I've had limited success.

Even using the demo located at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/spell-check/ produces no results.

For example, consider the following piece of text: "*Currently growing my **compny** which is a UK based Online **compny** with clients across the world. Working since 2001 to help **indivduals**.*"

This produces no results. I've looked at regional settings, PROOF vs SPELL, character counts to no avail.

Has anyone had any success with this service, or, even better, does the above text snippet produce results for you?

[image]

Comment: In my test, if split  the paragraph into two sentences, the  two sentences all could get right result, you could have a try.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but no joy, what did work is removing a lot of the words and it picked up some results. However this isn't a workable solution as the real world text may be quite lengthy and I wouldn't' want to split the text up per X words and make multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

Spell mode is working for me with your sample, see below:

[image: Sample]

The JSON result is:

```
{
  "_type": "SpellCheck",
  "flaggedTokens": [
    {
      "offset": 21,
      "token": "compny",
      "type": "UnknownToken",
      "suggestions": [
        {
          "suggestion": "company",
          "score": 0.9264452620075305
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "offset": 55,
      "token": "compny",
      "type": "UnknownToken",
      "suggestions": [
        {
          "suggestion": "company",
          "score": 0.8740149238635179
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "offset": 120,
      "token": "indivduals",
      "type": "UnknownToken",
      "suggestions": [
        {
          "suggestion": "individuals",
          "score": 0.753968656686115
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not 'Spell' mode, but 'Proof'. it is in your screenshot too.

Comment: Thanks Yegor, did it return anything for Spell mode?

Comment: No results with Spell mode

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a fair amount of trial I've had some success, which has solved some issues and created others. I've not been able to get a reliable result from Spell mode, but I have with Proof, however after adding a fairly short piece of text, it would again not report any results. Inspecting the API shows the text is encoded in the POST, removing both "%0D" and "%0A", line feed chars allows me to Proof long texts with success, which would be fine, however being UK based, lots of correct spellings are now flagged as incorrect as the PROOF mode is only available in the US. So, I've still been unable to solve getting a functioning SPELL result (which works for very short pieces of text). I understand the documentation states upto 130 chars for GET, but 10,000 chars for POST and my typical example POSTS are around 1,000 chars. Possibly a ticket with MS unless anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I guess there is no solution (the only one would be having 'en-gb' supported by proof mode), because the doc says that Spell mode is not the right one for you: 
Proof - Meant to provide Office Word like spelling corrections. It can correct long queries, provide casing corrections and suppresses aggressive corrections.
Spell - Meant to provide Search engine like spelling corrections. It will correct small queries(up to length 9 tokens) without any casing changes and will be more optimized (perf and relevance) towards search like queries.

Comment: I guess you're right Nicolas, very odd how MS would put a limit of 130 chars in for Spell, but 4,096 for Proof. It would have been nice if the API would have returned a message to indicate the max had been reached as opposed to doing nothing. I've moved onto another provider, as you suggest, no solution possible for now